# HP Color Laserjet M252dw does not print some files

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

I have a brand new HP Color Laserjet M252dw on Ubuntu 12.04LTS 32-bit with no hard disc.  Some pdfs print and some do not.  Some images which used to print now do not.  All the printer tests work.  Everything is up to date.  I have tried the PCL and generic Foomatic drivers drivers but it does not work to the same extent.  I wonder if there is a memory issue?  How do I fix it or debug it further?

Answer (score 0):

I have this printer and it works flawlessly with ubuntu linux , i am using the HP Color LaserJet Pro M252 Postscript (recommended) driver.

You will need some disk space for spooling to print.

Comment: For older installs you'll need to update hplip http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html to get the right driver